# How can I convert a null-terminated string in a byte buffer to a string in Go?

Tags: c, string, go

This:

```
label := string([]byte{97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0})
fmt.Printf("%s\n", label)
```

does this (`^@` is the null-byte):

```
go run test.go 
abc^@^@^@
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's this function hidden inside Go's syscall package that finds the first null byte ([]byte{0}) and returns the length. I'm assuming it's called clen for C-Length.

Sorry I'm a year late on this answer, but I think it's a *lot* simpler than the other two (no unnecessary imports, etc.)

```
func clen(n []byte) int {
    for i := 0; i < len(n); i++ {
        if n[i] == 0 {
            return i
        }
    }
    return len(n)
}
```

So,

```
label := []byte{97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0}
s := label[:clen(label)]
fmt.Println(string(s))
```

What that ^ says is to set `s` to the slice of bytes in `label` from the beginning to the index of `clen(label)`.

The result would be `abc` with a length of 3.

Comment: This is actually the cleanest, simplest and more efficient solution.

Comment: And, unlike the `string.Index` answer, this won't panic if the provided `[]byte` does *not* contain a zero byte.

Comment: This is the only correct solution so far. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm getting "clen" undefined and "imported and not used: syscall"

Answer (score 12):

Note that the first answer will only work with strings that have only a run of zeroes after the null terminator; however, a proper C-style null-terminated string ends at the first `\0` even if it's followed by garbage. For example, `[]byte{97,98,99,0,99,99,0}` should be parsed as `abc`, not `abc^@cc`.

To properly parse this, use `string.Index`, as follows, to find the *first* `\0` and use it to slice the original byte-slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    label := []byte{97,98,99,0,99,99,0}
    nullIndex := strings.Index(string(label), "\x00")
    if (nullIndex < 0) {
        fmt.Println("Buffer did not hold a null-terminated string")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(label[:nullIndex]))
}
```

EDIT: Was printing the shortened version as a `[]byte` instead of as a `string`. Thanks to @serbaut for the catch.

EDIT 2: Was not handling the error case of a buffer without a null terminator. Thanks to @snap for the catch.

Comment: Shouldnt that be string(label[:bytes.IndexByte(label, 0)])?

Comment: @serbaut, you're very correct; should have run that in play, and I would have noticed the []byte formatting. Edited

Comment: This panics if the input does not contain nul terminator. Not nice.

Comment: @snap Good catch! Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sys` package:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

func main() {
   b := []byte{97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   s := windows.ByteSliceToString(b)
   println(s == "abc")
}
```

Or you can just implement it yourself:

```
package main
import "bytes"

func byteSliceToString(s []byte) string {
   n := bytes.IndexByte(s, 0)
   if n >= 0 {
      s = s[:n]
   }
   return string(s)
}

func main() {
   b := []byte{97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   s := byteSliceToString(b)
   println(s == "abc")
}
```

- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#ByteSliceToString
- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#ByteSliceToString

Answer (score 1):

### 1. strings <del>.TrimSpace</del> .TrimRight

//trim tail '\0', but can't handle bytes like "abc\x00def\x00".

can't edit @orelli answer, so wrote here:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    label := string([]byte{97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0})

    s1 := strings.TrimSpace(label)
    fmt.Println(len(s1), s1)

    s2 := strings.TrimRight(label, "\x00")
    fmt.Println(len(s2), s2)
  }
```

output:

```
7 abc????
3 abc
```

// ? is '\0' which can't display here.

So
`.TrimSpace` can't trim '\0', but
`.TrimRight` with "\x00" can.

### 2. bytes.IndexByte

search for first '\0', maybe not support utf-8

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    b_arr := []byte{97, 98, 99, 0, 100, 0, 0}
    label := string(b_arr)

    s1 := strings.TrimSpace(label)
    fmt.Println(len(s1), s1)   //7 abc?d??

    s2 := strings.TrimRight(label, "\x00")
    fmt.Println(len(s2), s2)   //5 abc?d

    n := bytes.IndexByte([]byte(label), 0)
    fmt.Println(n, label[:n])  //3 abc

    s_arr := b_arr[:bytes.IndexByte(b_arr, 0)]
    fmt.Println(len(s_arr), string(s_arr)) //3 abc
}
```

equivalent

```golang
n1 := bytes.IndexByte(b_arr, 0)
n2 := bytes.Index(b_arr, []byte{0})

n3, c := 0, byte(0)
for n3, c = range b_arr {
    if c == 0 {
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bytes.SplitN` and have it return the first subslice:

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
)

func bytesToStr(in []byte) string {
    str := bytes.SplitN(in, []byte{0}, 2)[0]
    return string(str)
}
```

In go 1.18+, you can also use `bytes.Cut`:

```golang
func bytesToStr(in []byte) string {
    str, _, _ := bytes.Cut(in, []byte{0})
    return string(str)
}
```