# How to call a function in a custom dll file

Tags: go

now i got this function describe like this

```
int ReadCard(char *room,char *gate,char *stime, char *guestname, char *guestid, char *lift, char *track1, char *track2, long *cardno, int *st, int *Breakfast);`
```

and this is what i do

```
room := ""
gate := ""
stime := ""
guestname := ""
guestid := ""
lift := ""
track1 := ""
track2 := ""
cardno := int64(0)
st := int64(0)
Breakfast := int64(0)

MAINDLL, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("xxxxx.dll")
defer syscall.FreeLibrary(MAINDLL)
readCard, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(MAINDLL, "ReadCard")

r1, r2, errno := syscall.Syscall12(readCard,
    11,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&room)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&gate)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&stime)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&guestname)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&guestid)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lift)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&track1)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&track2)),
    uintptr(cardno),
    uintptr(st),
    uintptr(Breakfast),
    0)

fmt.Println(r1, "\n", r2, "\n", errno)`
```

when i run this code , i got

```
r1:0    r2:917452    errno:<nil>
```

but when i print room or other param , it's value doesn't change,
this function in dll file will change the param i send , how can i got those value?

Comment: *Who* will allocate the memory for storing those values(`room`, `gate`, etc)? DLL or Golang side?

Comment: the golang side ,but i don't know how many the dll func will use ,like the param `lift` ,it's result may be `99` or `01020304` or even much longer

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve C's *NULL terminated string*, use pointer to *pre-allocated byte slice* instead of `string`. You need to make sure that the *byte slice* has enough space for storing the character, otherwise your program may crash due to memory access violation.

For `long *` and `int *` type, address to the variable is needed, e.g. use `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&cardno))` instead of `uintptr(cardno)`. In your current implementation, the value pointed by the variable is converted to a pointer. All `uintptr(cardno)`, `uintptr(st)`, `uintptr(Breakfast)` point to the same *pointer* (pointer to `NULL` in C) since they're all initialized to 0.

The code looks like:

```
const maxSize = 100 //Adjust the value to your need

room := make([]byte, maxSize)
gate := make([]byte, maxSize)
stime := make([]byte, maxSize)
guestname := make([]byte, maxSize)
guestid := make([]byte, maxSize)
lift := make([]byte, maxSize)
track1 := make([]byte, maxSize)
track2 := make([]byte, maxSize)

//The following variable type is correct for 64-bit DLL.
//For 32-bit DLL, instead of int64, use int32.
cardno := int64(0)
st := int64(0)
Breakfast := int64(0)

MAINDLL, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("xxxxx.dll")
defer syscall.FreeLibrary(MAINDLL)
readCard, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(MAINDLL, "ReadCard")

r1, r2, errno := syscall.Syscall12(readCard,
    11,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&room[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&gate[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&stime[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&guestname[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&guestid[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lift[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&track1[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&track2[0])),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&cardno)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&st)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&Breakfast)),
    0)

fmt.Println(r1, "\n", r2, "\n", errno)
```

Note that in the above example, we're using `&room[0]` intead of `room`, since we need to pass address of underlying byte array instead of address of the slice descriptor (See https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Finally, the byte slice which holds *NULL terminated string* must be converted to `go`'s `string`, e.g. using:

```
func cstr(buf []byte) string {
    str := string(buf)
    for i, r := range str {
        if r == 0 {
            return string(buf[:i])
        }
    }
    return str
}

//usage example
sRoom := cstr(room)
//see the difference
fmt.Printf("`%s` => `%s`\n", string(room), sRoom)
```

Other implementation example, see [How can I convert a null-terminated string in a byte buffer to a string in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359777/how-can-i-convert-a-null-terminated-string-in-a-byte-buffer-to-a-string-in-go).